# Visual Studio Code and Laravel commands

Tags: php, laravel, macos, laravel-5, visual-studio-code

I have MacBook and I use Visual Studio Code.
I am beginner with Laravel. I use Laravel 5.8 in my project.

When I open `command+shift+p` and choose: **Artisan Migrate Fresh**

I get this error:

> [ERR] Command failed: cd "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/symfonia/" && "php" artisan migrate:fresh  --seed

How can I fix it?

Comment: at some point in visual studio code config, you can set the path to php ... i do not run this command from vscode, but maybe it helps

Comment: where to do it?

Comment: In your settings, set the `php.executablePath`